# Filtering and calculating mean within groups ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2, dplyr, filter, group-by, statistics

I'm working with a large df trying to make some plots by filterig data through different attributes of interest. Let's say my df looks like:

df(site=c(A,B,C,D,E), subsite=c(w,x,y,z), date=c(01/01/1985, 05/01/1985, 16/03/1995, 24/03/1995), species=c(1,2,3,4), Year=c(1985,1990,1995,2012), julian day=c(1,2,3,4), Month=c(6,7,8,11).

I would like plot the average julian day per month each year in which a species was present in a Subsite and Site. So far I've got this code but the average has been calculated for each month over all the years in my df rather than per year. Any help/ directions would be welcome!

```
Plot1<- df %>% 
  filter(Site=="A", Year>1985, Species =="2")%>%
  group_by(Month) %>% 
  mutate("Day" = mean(julian day)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Year, y=Day, color=Species)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", 
               shape=1, size=1, show.legend=FALSE) + 
  stat_summary(fun=mean, colour="red", geom="text", show.legend = FALSE, 
               vjust=-0.7,size=3, aes(label=round(..y.., digits=0)))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I spotted the error.

I was missing this:

```
group_by(Month, **Year**) %>%
```